# How to test for linear Independence for square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been doing many exercises regarding linear independence, especially those about how to verify if a given set of vectors are linearly independent or dependent.

In those exercises, vectors are all in column form such as:  $\begin{pmatrix} 1  \\  2 \\  3 \\  4 \end{pmatrix}$. So, I simply put all the vectors column-by-column along with zero vector into an augmented matrix to test their linear independence.

However, I have just seen questions where vectors involved are square matrices such as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ 3 & 4   \end{pmatrix}$. Suppose we have four vectors in such form, I am not sure in what way should I put them to test linear independence?

Comment: One approach is to note that the vector space of real $2\times 2$ matrices isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, so you can always express this question in terms of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: @NoahSolomon and for non-square ones?

Comment: The real vector space of $m \times n$ matrices is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. To see why this is true, simply consider the map which sends basis elements from one to the other. You can actually make much stronger claims about finite dimensional vector spaces, but the matrix case is particuarly easy to see.